# How are the inside front tyres wearing down so quickly- Ford KA

Tags: tires

History: After 5 (Oct 17) months the front driver side tyre was worn down on the inner shoulder/rib and the wires were showing. So I bought a new tyre (GoodYear brand) and had it fitted. After about a 13 months later (today) the tyre is completely worn on the inside ! I don't do a lot of miles I have only done about 2k+ miles using that tyre.

Somewhat similar to this image (this is from google but it looks close enough to my tyre on both ocassions).

[image]

The front passenger tyre was fine since Oct 17, and recently it has worn down a lot on the inside, the inner shoulder is worn down but the wires aren't showing yet.

Now, I'm going to fit two new tyres make sure they will be balanced and get tracking done. Just before finding out the front tyres are in this state I found out that the driver side wheel bearing is gone and the link arm could this have accelerated the wear on the tyre? - Of course this is assumed that those parts were broken for a while in order to do this. HOWEVER, that being said, this isn't the first time the front tyre has wear on the inside - oct 2017? And I don't think I spent 13 months with a broken wheel bearing or link arm

What is causing this, I don't want to keep buying new tyres :(

I also have another question, I overinflate my tyres, 50% of the time I have one passenger, and 50% im driving alone, and the manual reccomends that the tyres are 33 psi or something like that (just for example im giving numbers) and if you have 3 or more passengers then 38 so I just do 38 psi. Now I found out this can cause wear on the tyres I won't be doing this again, but according to this (see pic) overinflating causes the center to get worn not the shoulder. So I don't know how reliable this is as a source?

[image]

---

**Sep 15 '18 at 14:18:**

So I fitted the two new tyres and got the tracking done. The tracker was reading the driver side as toe out and the laser read it as 5 and the passenger side as toe out and at 6. The scale's maximum was 10 so mine was halfway to being completely misaligned. Now the driver side is 1 and the other side is -1, total 0 and the point is that they need to cancel each other see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJrImcAHk2Y) for more info [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4romn.jpg) is an image of my ACTUAL TYRE before changing it.

**April 2019: Tyres still going strong!**

Indeed it was the alignment causing all the issues!

Comment: The photo shows a serious alignment problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lopsided tyre wear like this is most often caused by wheel misalignment - either toe or camber. Most decent tyre shops these days can do a full laser alignment check and will give you a printout to show what it's like - they usually do the check for free and charge for the adjustment.

The alignment will certainly be made worse by a failing wheel bearing or link arm, so get those fixed first.

Answer (score 3):

There is something VERY wrong with your front wheel alignment, especially if this is only happening to one front tyre. If you bought the car second-hand, could it have been involved in a serious crash that nobody told you about? I would suggest getting a Ford main dealer (not a tyre garage) to look at it, and check the whole subframe is properly aligned, not just "details" like the wheel bearings and suspension links.

The picture doesn't look like the "normal" wear pattern from poor wheel alignment. It looks as if the tire is only in contact with the road along that inside edge - the rest of the tread looks hardly worn at all.

From your post you don't drive very high mileage, but it seems remarkable that you haven't noticed any handling problems - e.g. the car is "wandering" from a straight line, or it veers off to one side when the steering wheel is in its central position.

The Halfords picture is correct. Over-inflation will wear the centre of the tread faster than the sides. Even under-inflation wouldn't cause the damage shown in your picture, unless the tire was almost completely "flat" - and then you would expect to see damage on *both* sides, and to the side walls as well.

Comment: So regarding the accident if it was in a serious accident then it wouldve been registered as a category d or c (aka N and S now). And thank you for helping be realise the severity of the issue because how could tracking do so much damage. I hope to take it to a ford dealership soon :)

Comment: So I fitted the two new tyres and got the tracking done. The tracker was reading the driver side as toe out and the lazer read it as 5 and the passenger side as toe out and at 6. The scale's maximum was 10 so mine was half way to being completely misaligned. Now the driver side is 1 and the other side is -1, total 0 and the point is that they need to cancel each other  see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJrImcAHk2Y) for more info

[Here](https://imgur.com/a/dqUYbxW) is a image of my ACTUAL TYRE before changing it.

Answer (score -1):

You have or had excessive NEGATIVE camber on the right hand side hence the tyre wear on the inside.

Comment: What does this answer offer compared to those here already?

Comment: He's the only one that notes negative camber.

Comment: @DavidWatson - No. If you look at NickC's answer, you'll see he does mention camber as an issue.